# Extend a class to DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want to create a custom DownloadManager class in which I want to modify the notification sent by the class during download and other stuff. Is it possible to do so or am I getting crazy? My main motive is to show my custom download notification even I close the app. Currently I am using DownloadManager class with notification disabled and then I run a timer to continuously monitor it and send my custom notification. But when I close my app, the thread stops(but DownloadManager still runs) and notification hangs there. I just want my custom notification to keep updating even after the app closes (as DownloadManager is still running).

I even try making a broadcast in the app and register in the manifest, but in android 3.1+ devices, the  receiver don't receive broadcast after app is closed. So, I am searching a solution for this. Hope I explained well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Download Manager` is system service, so you can use it but not really alter the way it works by extending anything. If you want file download to behave different way, you have to handle file downloads yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to run some piece of code even if i close my app?

Comment: You can try to use Alarm Manager or try to listen to system broadcast (fi there's any that is related to your task)

Comment: Can you suggest any tutorial please?